# Cookies Android, some clarifications

Tags: android, cookies

I'm getting a little confused about cookies especially after having implemented the iOS version of this problem.

I want to use a cookie to save data after the user has logged on. With this cookie, the user shouldn't have to log in again(or for a long period of time). I've seen several different android implementations and perhaps I'm being naive but I expected it to be more simplistic. So a couple of questions:

1. How do I find what cookies I already have? Do I need to use a CookieManager or a CookieStore. I notice with that there are two different definitions of these, one for Java and the other for Android? Is one better than the other.
2. Do I need an DefaultHTTPClient? When I initialise the httpClient, do I need to store any sort of reference to the client that created the cookie?

Any explanations on the general process would also be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are cookies a hard requirement, or can the API return the information in `json`?

Comment: I'm downloading the "cookie" itself from the server and the file itself contains json. I want to store it and have access to it over multiple sessions. I'm open to all ideas regarding whether its actually a cookie or not.

Comment: In the ios version I ended up initilaising the NSCookie with the dictionary and saved it. The android version seems to require much more setting up...

Comment: You don't have to use cookies, it is just a storage mechanism. Check out SharedPreferences, it can only be accessed using the app that set them. You can use that just like a NSCookie dictionary in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `SharedPreferences` for the task you are asking about, but doing some more research would definitely benefit you in the future.

The [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) has a really good page on storage options and how/when to use them.

**Example:**

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
String token = settings.getString("sessionTokenCookie", false);
myAppSingleton.setToken(token);
```

Also, I would suggest using [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) for your HTTP library. This will take care of a lot of issues that you may experience using the Java or Apache implementation by themselves. You could then just add the token to the header on each request, getting it from the App Singleton you stored it in.